# How to stop the constant flickering while playing animation?

Tags: c, stdio, bgi, winbgi

I was trying to make a simple animation of a stickman walking, in `graphics` library in `C`.

*My code:*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<graphics.h>

void swap(int *x, int *y){

    int temp=0;
    temp=*x;
    *x=*y;
    *y=temp;
}


int main(){
    int gd=DETECT,gm=0;
    int i=0;
    int a=30+i;
    int b=50+i;
    initgraph(&gd,&gm,"C:\\TURBOC3\\BGI");
    while(i!=600){
    swap(&a,&b);
    circle(40+i,40,30);
    line(40+i,70,a+i,90);
    line(40+i,70,b+i,90);
    i++;
    delay(10);
    cleardevice();
    }
    getch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that, the monitor screen keeps flickering constantly while playing the animation and moreover, the leg positions are not swapping according to the `swap(&b,&c)` function. Where am I going wrong here? Can someone please help me?

**Fix:** So, I realised that, there's no point in having the `swap()` function as, swapping the lines will make the alignment same again for both of them (as a result it will look like the legs are not moving), so I decided to tweak some things here:

```
while(i!=600){
    if(i%2==0){
        circle(40+i,40,30);
        line(40+i,70,(a+b)/2+i,90);
        line(40+i,70,(b+a)/2+i,90);

    }else{
        circle(40+i,40,30);
        line(40+i,70,a+i,90);
        line(40+i,70,b+i,90);
    }
    i++;
    delay(10);
    cleardevice();
    }
```

Now, it actually looks like the figure is walking. But I still don't know how to fix the screen flickering problem.

Comment: Have you ever head of [*page flipping*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639408/what-does-it-mean-by-page-flipping-in-computer-graphics-programming) ? That's one way to eliminate flicker, and yes, it can be a pain. If your graphics library supports it, consider it, or something similar.

Comment: @FMA either use buffering like WhozCraig suggested or render incrementaly (which still flickers but a lot less) ... you main problem now is the `cleardevice()` ... PS buffering is much much easier to implement and does not flicker at all ... IIRC BGI have some functions in it to support buffering

Comment: Learn to debug, at least put some `printf()` at strategic places to watch your variables `b` and `c`. This will help you find that issue. BTW, the code of `swap()` has no obvious error.

Comment: @thebusybee sorry, I debugged and checked that the `swap()` function was working. But it was pointless in this code.

Comment: Did you consider using frame buffers and switch these? You erase a non-visible buffer and draw in it as slow as it goes, and then exchange it in a blink. Visit the given URL and learn about the issue.

Comment: Be sure to hook the vertical retrace interrupt.  Then when the interrupt occurs, do the image flip.  Then the image flipping will not cause a flickering screen

Comment: regarding: `#include<graphics.h>`   The `graphics.h` is from the days of DOS.  Much better to use a 'modern' graphics library